# UINavigationController with presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a menu screen that implements `UINavigationController` and on top of that screen, using `presentModalViewController`, I place another screen on which I want to have another `UINavigationController`. I have tried to implement another navigation controller to handle the new screen but I either get a navbar 1/8th the way down the screen and it crashes or nothing at all. I have tried `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationConroller]` with no success as well. I'm just using `pushViewController` to try and place the next nib on the stack which doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will probably won't get any responses until you post your code to show what you are doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although there are a lot of people saying on forums that Apple doesn't allow this I have got it to work. What you have to do is:

```
Map *mapScreen = [[[Map alloc] init] autorelease];
mapScreen.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapScreen] autorelease];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This is the method I use as well, a UINavigationController is simply a subclass of a UIViewController, and you can do all the same things with it as you would do with a UIViewController.

Comment: This is the technique that Apple describes in the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS: Modal View Controllers. Perhaps people were commenting on your unnecessary use of autorelease. When you use presentModalViewController: mapScreen and navController are both retained by self, and can be accessed through self.modalViewController, so you can and should release both right away.

Comment: Huh? its just the example, I don't use autorelease normally but just for easy of the example I put it here as autorelease, means people know that it should be released. This is also very old and most forums at the time said you couldn't do it, hence the first statement in the answer.